# How can I remove the first part of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

For example, I have a variable that I've already defined that I want to use as a counter in a for loop. I've found that replacing the first expression with null works, but I was wondering if I could remove it entirely with a different version of a for loop.

Example:

```
function foo() {
    var i = 10;
    for(null; i > 0; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just leave the initializer empty.

Comment: You'll be amazed at what you can learn if you read documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Examples In fact your example's function body is almost exactly a copy of the "optional" example in the docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just don't supply anything. All 3 parts of a `for` loop are optional.

```
function foo() {
    var i = 10;
    for(; i > 0; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function foo() {
    var i = 10;
    while(i++ > 0){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

But its never-ending loop =) You can use simply `true`:

```
while(true){
    ...
}
```